Confusion about the LCAO or tight binding model (nearest neighbors)
I'm using the book "Atomic and Electronic Structure of Solids" by Kaxiras. In chapter 4, the author introduces the tight binding or LCAO model for calculating electronic band structures. He supposes the atomic states can be written as:
$$\chi _{li}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum e^{i \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{R'}} \phi_l (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t_i}-\mathbf{R'}) $$
The sum is over all unit cells, represented by $\mathbf{R'}$. The index $i$ represents one of the atoms in the unit cell and the index $l$ represents the choice of orbital. The $\phi$ functions are localized around $\mathbf{t_i}$ and form an orthogonal basis.
With this, the Hamiltonian matrix elements can be calculated as:
$$\langle \chi_{mj}|H|\chi_{li}\rangle = \sum_{\mathbf{R}}e^{i \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{R}} \langle \phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_j)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_i-\mathbf{R})\rangle$$
I'm confused about how to calculate these elements. For simplicity, assume only the nearest neighbors contribute to the $\mathbf{R}$ sum. In one of my classes, the Hamiltonian of a diatomic 1D chain with interatomic spacing $a$ was calculated, considering only the $s$ orbital. The elements in the diagonal are simply constants, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$. Using the above formula for the matrix elements, I get:
$$H_{s1,s1}= \langle\phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)\rangle + e^{ika}\langle\phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1-\mathbf{a})\rangle+e^{-ika}\langle\phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1+\mathbf{a})\rangle$$
The first term represents the constant, but what about the other two terms? The only thing I can think about is that, since the $\phi$ functions are localized, the overlap integrals go to $0$ because they are localized about different atoms in the chain.
Similarly, the off-diagonal elements in my class were calculated to be cosines. Using the formula, I would get the overlap integral between the functions of both atoms, plus exponential terms that I assume have the same constant and sum into a cosine. This overlap integral would now be the one to go to $0$.
Is this logic reasonable? Do you think that my class calculations are further approximations?

The overlap integrals do NOT vanish. They will be some small numbers, but with some overlap, they will be non-zero. You are correct that, essentially, the two overlap integrals end up being the same, and so can be factorised out of the sum of exponentials, and thus the sum of exponentials give you the cosine.


$$H_{s1,s1}= \langle\phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)\rangle + e^{ika}\langle\phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1-\mathbf{a})\rangle+e^{-ika}\langle\phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1+\mathbf{a})\rangle$$


The first term represents the constant, but what about the other two terms?

The other two terms are basically the hopping terms. They are "small" since the two orbital do not overlap much, but they are not zero (unless some symmetry forces it to be zero).
If you call your constant term $E_0$, so $\langle\phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)\rangle = E_0$, and if you call your other matrix element $t$, so $t=\langle\phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_1-\mathbf{a})\rangle$, you have:
$$
H_{s1,s1} = E_0 + 2t\cos(ka)\;.
$$
Above, I am playing fast and loose with the index symbols, but this is partially due to the fact that I can not make sense of which of the indices are supposed to be free, which are summed, and the fact that the indices don't seem to match up on the two sides of your equations.
Below, I will provide an extended answer and I will use my own notation.

Consider the general independent-particle approximation to the Hamiltonian of a solid:
$$
\hat H_1 = \int \hat \psi^\dagger(\vec r)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 + U(\vec r)\right)\hat \psi(\vec r)\;,\tag{1}
$$
where $e=\hbar=m=1$ and where $U(\vec r)$ is the periodic potential of the solid and where $\hat \psi(\vec r)$ is an electron creation operator. Clearly, we are ignoring the electron-electron interactions (or we are treating them within a mean-field or DFT-based approximation).
We can expand $H_1$ in any basis we like, but it helps if the basis has some nice completeness and orthogonality properties. For my expansion, I will choose Wannier functions, which you can think of as a generalization of atomic orbitals at a given site. I will denote a Wannier function associated with lattice site $\vec R$ as:
$$
W_{\vec R,n}(\vec r)\;,
$$
where the $n$ index can be thought of as an atomic orbital index, but is somewhat generalized. (Similar to how I have to use $\vec k$ and $n$ for Bloch waves, I need to use $\vec R$ and $n$ for Wannier functions.)
Expanding in Wannier functions as
$$
\hat \psi(\vec r) = \sum_{\vec R,n}\hat c_{\vec R,n}W_{\vec R,n}(\vec r)
$$
gives:
$$
\hat H_1 = \sum_{\vec R, \vec R', n, n'}c_{\vec R',n'}^\dagger c_{\vec R,n} h_{n',n}(\vec R', \vec R)\;,
$$
where
$$
h_{n',n}(\vec R', \vec R) = \int d^3r W^*_{\vec R',n'}(\vec r)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 + U(\vec r)\right)W_{\vec R, n}(\vec r)\;.
$$
The terms for which $\vec R=\vec R'$ are the on-site terms (e.g., $h_{n',n}(0) = \delta_{n',n}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{\vec k}\epsilon^{(n)}(\vec k)$, where the $\epsilon^{(n)}(\vec k)$ is the Bloch wave band structure).
The terms for which $\vec R\neq \vec R'$ are the "hopping terms." Assuming the Wannier functions are localized similarly to atomic orbitals, one usually one looks at the nearest neighbor or next-nearest neighbor hopping terms.


With this, the Hamiltonian matrix elements can be calculated as:
$$\langle \chi_{mj}|H|\chi_{li}\rangle = \sum_{\mathbf{R}}e^{i \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{R}} \langle \phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_j)|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}_i-\mathbf{R})\rangle$$
I'm confused about how to calculate these elements.

In general it is hard to calculate the matrix elements exactly, but to get an idea of the different pieces, recall that if the potential $U(\vec r)$ is approximately the same as the atomic potential near a site and if the orbital is well localized, then you have:
$$
\langle \phi_m(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t}-\mathbf{a})|H|\phi_l(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{t})\rangle
$$
$$
=\int d^3r \phi_m^*(\vec r - \vec a)(-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 + U(\vec r))\phi_l(\vec r)
$$
$$
\approx
\int d^3r \phi_m^*(\vec r - \vec a)(-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 + \frac{Z_a}{|r|}+\frac{Z_a}{|\vec r - \vec a|} +\Delta U(\vec r))\phi_l(\vec r)
$$
$$
\approx \varepsilon_l \int d^3r \phi_m^*(\vec r - \vec a)\phi_l(\vec r)
+Z_a\int  d^3r \phi_m^*(\vec r - \vec a)\phi_l(\vec r)\frac{1}{|\vec r - \vec a|}
+\int d^3r \phi_m^*(\vec r - \vec a)\phi_l(\vec r)\Delta U(\vec r)
$$
where the first term is the atomic site energy, the second term is from the part of the potential near $\vec t -\vec a$, and the third term $\Delta U$ accounts for all the other pieces of the potential that are not near either $\vec t$ or $\vec t - \vec a$ (and so possibly expected to be negligible).

Thanks for the detailed answer. I got in contact with my professor and the explanation to my confusion is pretty simple. For the diatomic chain, the diagonal terms of the Hamiltonian (considering only first neighbours, should simply be the constant. The cosine term you calculated above appears if you consider second neighbours. The reason is very simple: for atom number 1, its neighbours are two atoms of the other species. The next closest atom of the same atomic species is a second neighbour.

@agaminon I glad you got it all sorted out.
